# Controls DistanceMeasurement,Overview and ContextMenu

Tags: here-api

Does anybody know how to enable the next controls in the here api 3.0?

- DistanceMeasurement
- Overview
- ContextMenu

I've reviewed the documentation but I cant find the classes or methods for enable that controls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

You can add a simple *overview* based on the synchronize two maps example in the [API Playground](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/synchronising-two-maps). Just append a new `<div>` within the first map using  `map.getElement()` and add a `mapviewchange` event which tracks the movement of the original map. You can alter the CSS as necessary to make it prettier.

```
/**
 * 
 *  @param  {H.Map} map  A HERE Map instance within the application
 *  @param  {H.service.Platform} platform
 */

function synchronizeMaps(map, platform) {
   var that = this;
   var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.style.width = '30%';
    div.style.height = '30%';
    div.style.top = '70%';
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';


    that.zoomOffset = -5;
    map.getElement().appendChild(div);

    map.addEventListener('mapviewchange',  function () {
      that.overviewMap.setCenter(map.getCenter());
      that.overviewMap.setZoom(map.getZoom() + zoomOffset);
    });


    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    that.overviewMap = new H.Map(div, defaultLayers.normal.map, {
      center: map.getCenter(),
      zoom: map.getZoom() + zoomOffset
    });

}
```

The result is something like this:

[image: London with Overview]

**DistanceMeasurement and ContextMenu**

Both of these controls rely on the use of the right click mouse button. Therefore they will not work on tablets or mobile phones. I guess this is the reason the components have not been included in the 3.0 API. I have no boilerplate to recreate the *DistanceMeasurement* use case (which is rather complex), but for a *ContextMenu* equivalent, you could perhaps utilize the `tap` event and create `<div>` on screen (again using  `map.getElement()`) - something like:

```
map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
     var div = document.createElement('div'); // or check if it already exists...

        div.style.width = '100px';
        div.style.height = '100px';
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
        div.style.position = 'absolute';
        div.style.left = evt.currentPointer.viewportX;
        div.style.top = evt.currentPointer.viewportY;

     map.getElement().appendChild(div);

  });
```

The real solution for *DistanceMeasurement* and *ContextMenu* is to remove them and update your UX to be mobile friendly. If you don't need to design for mobile or tablet then I would continue using the 2.5.x API.